# replacing "__attribute__ ((packed))" for compact structures by a standard (portable) C method

Tags: c, gcc, alignment, packed

Conversion of several values to a byte-string for radio transmission has to avoid unneeded bytes. Using GCC on an ARM target (32 bit) I use "**attribute** ((packed))". This directive is GCC based (as I read somewhere here) and so not generally portable - which I would prefer. Example:

```
typedef struct __attribute__ ((packed)) {
    uint8_t     u8;  // (*)
    int16_t     i16; // (*)
    float       v;
    ...
    uint16_t    cs;  // (*)
}valset_t;           // valset_t is more often used 
valset_t   vs;
```

(*) values would use 4 bytes without the ((packed)) attribute, instead of one or two as desired. Byte-wise access for transmission with:

```
union{
    valset_t    vs;                     // value-set
    uint8_t     b[sizeof(valset_t)];    // byte array
}vs_u;
```

using vs_u.b[i] .

- Processing time is not critical here, as the transmission is much slower.
- Endian is also not to be considered here, but a different C-compiler might be applied in some cases.
- Elder posts to this task gave some insight, but maybe packing and alignment features were improved meanwhile in C ?c) .

Is there a more portable solution in C to perform this task?

Answer (score 2):

Packing/padding isn't standardized, and therefore structs/unions are strictly speaking not portable. `#pragma pack(1)` is somewhat more common and supported by many different compilers (including gcc), but it is still not fully portable.

Also please note that padding exists for a reason, these structs with non-standard packing could be dangerous or needlessly inefficient on some systems.

The only 100% portable data type for storing protocols etc is an array of `unsigned char`. You can get only get fully portable structs if you write serializer/deserializer routines for them. This naturally comes at the expense of extra code. Example of deserialization:

```
valset_t data_to_valset (const unsigned char* data)
{
  valset_t result;
  result.something = ... ;
  ...
  return result;
}
```

In case of a certain network endianess, you can convert from network endianess to CPU endianess inside the same routine.

Please note that you *have* to type it out like in the function example above. You *cannot* write code such as:

```
unsigned char data[n] = ... ;
valset_t* vs = (valset_t*)data; // BAD
```

This is bad in multiple different ways: alignment, padding, strict aliasing, endianess and so on.

It is possible to go the other way around though, using a `unsigned char*` to inspect or serialize a struct byte by byte. However, doing so doesn't solve the issues of padding bytes or endianess still.